# Unable to download pre-trained model from zoo

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am unable to download model files from the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)
The download API response is 206. I am not sure whether only i am facing this issue or everyone?

Is there any other alternative way to download the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to open a new tab and paste a link to the model there.
When I simply tried clicking on the github page to download models directly it didn't work.
Copy and paste of the url on a fresh tab worked ok. I got one 206 (see screenshot) but the same file worked OK shortly after.

[image]